# How to take the body from response coming in console and assign to particular objects in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a set of links, i need to read each link and assign to its particular object.

**TS:**

```
exportUrl: any = {
    patient: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient/Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    medication: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/MedicationOrder?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    condition: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Condition?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    allergy: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/AllergyIntolerance?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    immunization: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Immunization?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    diagnostic: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/DiagnosticReport?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    observation: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Observation?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB&code=8310-5",
    procedure: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Procedure?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    device: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Device?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    careplan: "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/CarePlan?patient=Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB"
};
constructor(private http: Http) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('data', data);
        })
```

Here i am not able to get data._body it throws an error in code

Working link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9vwzq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Console:**

```
{
    "resourceType": "Patient",
    "birthDate": "1985-08-01",
    "active": true,
    "gender": "male",
    "deceasedBoolean": false,
    "id": "Tbt3KuCY0B5PSrJvCu2j-PlK.aiHsu2xUjUM8bWpetXoB",
    "careProvider": [{
        "display": "Physician Family Medicine",
        "reference": "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Practitioner/T3Mz3KLBDVXXgaRoee3EKAAB"
    }],
    "name": [{
        "use": "usual",
        "text": "Jason Argonaut",
        "family": ["Argonaut"],
        "given": ["Jason"]
    }],
    "identifier": [{
        "use": "usual",
        "system": "urn:oid:1.2.840.114350.1.13.327.1.7.5.737384.0",
        "value": "E3826"
    }, {
        "use": "usual",
        "system": "urn:oid:1.2.3.4",
        "value": "203579"
    }],
    "address": [{
        "use": "home",
        "line": ["1979 Milky Way Dr."],
        "city": "Verona",
        "state": "WI",
        "postalCode": "53593",
        "country": "US"
    }, {
        "use": "temp",
        "line": ["5301 Tokay Blvd"],
        "city": "MADISON",
        "state": "WI",
        "postalCode": "53711",
        "country": "US",
        "period": {
            "start": "2011-08-04T00:00:00Z",
            "end": "2014-08-04T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }],
    "telecom": [{
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "608-271-9000",
        "use": "home"
    }, {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "608-771-9000",
        "use": "work"
    }, {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "608-771-9000",
        "use": "mobile"
    }, {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "608-771-9000",
        "use": "home"
    }, {
        "system": "phone",
        "value": "608-771-9000",
        "use": "temp",
        "period": {
            "start": "2011-08-04T00:00:00Z",
            "end": "2014-08-04T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }, {
        "system": "email",
        "value": "open@epic.com"
    }],
    "maritalStatus": {
        "text": "Single",
        "coding": [{
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/marital-status",
            "code": "S",
            "display": "Never Married"
        }]
    },
    "communication": [{
        "preferred": true,
        "language": {
            "text": "English",
            "coding": [{
                "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.99",
                "code": "en",
                "display": "English"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "extension": [{
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-race",
        "valueCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Asian",
            "coding": [{
                "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.104",
                "code": "2028-9",
                "display": "Asian"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity",
        "valueCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Not Hispanic or Latino",
            "coding": [{
                "system": "2.16.840.1.113883.5.50",
                "code": "2186-5",
                "display": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/us-core-birth-sex",
        "valueCodeableConcept": {
            "text": "Male",
            "coding": [{
                "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/AdministrativeGender",
                "code": "M",
                "display": "Male"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What error does it throw?
What do you see in the console?

Comment: Property '_body' does not exist on type 'Response'.

Comment: What you got in console?

Comment: Post the output of console.log('data', data);

Comment: try with .body not ._body. Furthermore you can use type checking response like this.http.get<Patient>(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(patient => console.log(patient))

Comment: @HiteshKansagara i had updated question

Comment: @JEY ya i will try

Comment: @Bhrungarajni the .body is available only if you used the option {observe: 'response'}

Comment: so now what should i do? should i change the code?

Comment: you should use typechecking or if you want to access a field use data['myfieldname']

Comment: `Http` is deprecated, you must use `HttpClient`, [as per the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) and [the source code](https://angular.io/api/http/Http). But if you keep using Http, at least know that the body can be accessed with `data.json()`, and not `data._body` or `data.body`.

Comment: @trichetriche didn't see that good point !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the text method to get response body in text like:

```
data.text()
```

and if you want response body in json then use json method like:

```
data.json()

ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data.text());
console.log(data.json());
        })
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Now i have list of links na, so should i call those links one by one and push to particular object?

Comment: what is you requirement?

Comment: i need to read link to json and then bind that json to client

Comment: you have to fetch data from all link and assign in different object right?

Comment: ya, exportUrl: any = { this is only my object to this only i need to push

Comment: In which object you want to push?

Comment: i want to push to that object only, i mean exportUrl.patient

Comment: instead of link you want to push response there right?

Comment: ya exactly i need to do like this

Comment: ok then call all link and assign like exportUrl.patient = data.json()

Comment: no no, i have patient na, so json must be assigned to patient, then allergy is there na json of allergy to get binded to allergy so on i must do

Comment: ya il try and come back

Comment: @Bhrungarajni if you update your angular version it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the body of the response to a string with text() and assign that to whatever:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
      let body = data.text();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to get your data in `json` format then you can use `data.json()`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data.json());
  })
```

Working example is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knd3cq

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining the solution you are using angular 4 with Http. Http is deprecated in angular 4 in favor to HttpClient. You will need to update your module definition first.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule, // <- not HttpModule
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

Then you will need to inject HttpClient instead of Http

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Then you can do:

```
this.http.get(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
    console.log(data['resourceType']); // should log Patient
});
```

But the best things to do is to use typechecking response. First you need to create an interface representing you JSON like:

```
export interface Patient {
    active: boolean;
    resourceType: string;
    // ...
}
```

And update your code to:

```
this.http.get<Patient>(this.exportUrl.patient).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.resourceType); // should log Patient
});
```

Then to respect good practice a component shouldn't access HttpClient but it should request data through a Service

Comment: ya, but i am getting an error saying get is not present in HttpClientModule

Comment: Something must be wrong with the injection. It's HttpClient that must be injected in your component not HttpClientModule

Comment: ya i will check